# JQuery code to show/hide form elements

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form filled with 3 rows of checkboxes. I would only like the second two rows to be available if and only if the third checkbox only is checked in the first row. As of right now, I am getting all three rows showing all the time, so it is very possible that I am not calling JQuery correctly.

Also, it would be nice if the form automatically scaled to account for the loss/gain of rows when the hide/show. Does this happen automatically (I'm using Bootstrap if that makes a difference).

Here is the code:

**JQuery**

```
<body>
  <script>
    $(function showHide() {
        $("name=checkboxes").click(function() {
            if (($('.checkboxes-farms').prop('checked', true)) || $('.checkboxes-fields').prop('checked', true) || $('.checkboxes-cropzones').prop('checked', false)) {
                $('#group2').hide();
                $('#group3').hide();
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

**HTML**

```
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <!-- Form Name -->
          <legend>Select Entities to Search For</legend>
          <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
          <div class="form-group" id="group1">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">Table(s)</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-farms" value="1">
                  Farms
              </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-fields" value="3">
                  Fields
              </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-2">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-cropzones" value="5">
                  Cropzones
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
          <div class="form-group" id="group2">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">Cropyear</label>
            <div class="col-md-4"> 
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxess-0">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes-lower" id="checkboxes-cropyear" value="2014">
                  2014
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
          <div class="form-group" id="group3">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">Crop</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes-lower" id="checkboxes-corn" value="100">
                  Corn
              </label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes-lower" id="checkboxes-soybeans" value="200">
                  Soybeans
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

Comment: Could you make http://jsbin.com demo?

Comment: function showHide().. you have nt called this function anywhere

Comment: $("name=checkboxes") whatttt??????????? :D

Comment: Fixed some bugs for. I hope you can take it from here http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/P4KKd/ :)
Tip. Always look for errors in your console. Have a look at http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide1 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('[name="checkboxes"]').on('change', function() {
        var others_checked = $('#checkboxes-fields, #checkboxes-farms').is(':checked');
        $('#group2, #group3').toggle($('#checkboxes-cropzones').is(':checked') && !(others_checked));
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jv6D/1/)

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clearer, but the second two rows should not be available if the third checkbox AND any of the other two are checked

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='checkboxes']").change(function () {
        if (($('#checkboxes-farms').prop('checked') == false) && ($('#checkboxes-fields').prop('checked') == false) && ($('#checkboxes-cropzones').prop('checked') == true)) {
            $('#group2,#group3').show();
        } else {
            $('#group2,#group3').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4bHk/)

Comment: Works great in the fiddle, but doesn't in the html itself, am I calling the function incorrectly by just sticking your answer in a `<script></script>` tag? btw, +1

Comment: thanks :) write under `ready` function. Like `$(document).ready(function(){$("input[name='checkboxes']").change........});`

Answer (score -1):

You need to hide them initially - would suggest doing this in the jquery document ready function e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready;
});
```

And I'd attach a 'change' event to the checkbox that controls the showing of the additional fields.

Let me know if you need an example popping together on jsfiddle or similar.